# How to update the rows of a table from another table? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to be able to update the data from one table to another without duplicating the rows that already exist in the table where the data will be copied.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

This is the structure of the table:

**TABLE1**

```
date       | value
-----------+----------
2018-05-09 |    27020
2018-05-08 |    27019
2018-05-07 |    27017
.
.
2011-05-08 |      128
```

**TABLE2**

```
date        |  value
------------+---------
2018-06-14  | 27402
2018-06-13  | 27401
2018-06-12  | 27400
.
.
2011-05-08  |   128
```

I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE2 
    WHERE ...
```

Comment: Mysql is not sql-server

Comment: If you want to update the table then use `UPDATE` not `INSERT INTO...`.

Comment: Well the OP definitely used the wrong terminology, but I am pretty sure they want inserts. Look at a `LEFT JOIN` with a where clause to filter out the "duplicate" values.

Comment: I know it isn't what you're asking, but maybe just create a view that includes both tables rather than updating a table and replicating data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to insert rows into table1 from table2 for the missing dates:

```
insert into table1 ([date], [value])
select [date], [value]
from table2 t2
where not exists (select * from table1 t3 where t3.[date] = t2.[date]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to insert the new records from `Table2` to `Table1` So you can use this query :

```
Insert into Table1 (date, value)
select date, value from Table2 
where not exists (
                select 1 from table1 where table1.[date] = table2.[date] and table1.value = table2.value
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into Table1 (date, value)
select date, value from Table2 EXCEPT SELECT date, value from Table1
```